# beginner having trouble making a persistent javadb database in java ee 7 and glassfish 4

Tags: jpa, glassfish, javadb

i have been programming code for over two decades, but am new to java ee 7.

i have purchased antonio gonclaves book and modified his code to get going, but can't quite get all of the details down to get the data to store in the database for future retrievals.

i simply want to have three strings entered in by the user, and have them listed on the same xhtml page in a datatable using jsf.

the jsf form works, as i can instantly see the results of the submitted form on my page.

the problem is that it seems like the object is not persisting in the database or even that the database is not even being created.

this is evident by the fact that the datatable is not generating new items.

is there any way to monitor the logs, or see what is going on behind the scenes? or, am i simply missing a little detail?

i can show my sections of my code if you ask.

### this is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="saciMataPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/nityanandaDB</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

---

as per the antonio gonclaves code from chapter 11 of his book, i created an entity class, a class that interfaces with the xhtml page, and an ejb class.

this is my EJB:

```
package gaurirasa.bhaktios.globallydevoted;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;


@Named
@Stateless
public class SaciMataEJB {

  // ======================================
  // =             Attributes             =
  // ======================================


  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "saciMataPU")
  private EntityManager em;

  // ======================================
  // =          Business methods          =
  // ======================================

  public Kurukshetra createKurukshetra(Kurukshetra kurukshetra) {
    em.persist(kurukshetra);
    return kurukshetra;
  }

  public List<Kurukshetra> findAllkurukshetras() {
    return em.createNamedQuery("findAllKurukshetras", Kurukshetra.class).getResultList();
  }

  public Kurukshetra findKurukshetraById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Kurukshetra.class, id);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, we ask for code, the minimum would be the jdbc connection string and the setup of your javadb (does it run embedded or standalone/network)

Comment: :)  i put the persistence.xml.   there would be no connection string in this case, i believe, as i am using JTA.  do i need to create the database before running the deployed application, or is the database created by this persistence.xml file?

Comment: Have you tried using `create` instead of `drop-and-create` ? But your `nityanandaDB` has to be mapped to javadb somewhere.

Comment: ok.  i see.  how do i map the nityanandaDB to javadb?

Comment: it does not look like i put any reference to the PersistenceUnit in the EJB.

Comment: ok.  i put in (at)PersistenceContext.  not sure if the (at)Produces is supposed to be there, or even what that does.

Comment: tried create insted of drop-and-create.  still no difference.

Comment: is there someway to get in there and see whats going on behind the scenes with the logs?

Comment: created the nityanandaDB, but still no change in the behavior of the web app

Comment: maybe i need to create a jdbc resource in the glassfish server...

Comment: ok.  working on creating a jdbc connection pool resource in the glassfish server

Comment: looks like __default derbypool is already there.  i might try to use that one.

Comment: got it!  great!  thanks @Marged !  your general advice pointed me in the right direction.  I had to change the persistence.xml '<jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/nityanandaDB</jta-data-source>' to '<jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>' and that made it connect to the default derby connection pool.

Comment: Great. I didn't have the solution but somehow helped you find it on your own ;-) In my opinion these are the best solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**solved**

After the help from **Marged**, it was eventually clear that all that was needed to be done was to modify the jta-data-source in the persistence.xml file.  i was basically under a lack of conceptual understanding of the process of connecting to a glassfish resource.

old jta-data-source:

```
<jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/nityanandaDB</jta-data-source>
```

new jta-data-source:

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/__default</jta-data-source>
```

this modification simply uses the default derby connection pool as its database resource.

*also, during the troubleshooting, i went ahead and created a database using the ij command line tool*